# Pass data from request object to template node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller, request

I am using the `request` package to make GET requests. I am trying to pass data from the request to my template as a callback but I keep getting the error `res.render is not a function`. Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
request("http://localhost:3000/api/employee", function(err, res, body) {

    var apiResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    var context = {
        name: apiResponse[0].first_name
    }
    res.render('../views/home', context);
});
};
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
request("http://localhost:3000/api/employee", function(err, response, body) {

    var apiResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    var context = {
        name: apiResponse[0].first_name
    }
    res.render('../views/home', context);
});
};
```

Please use this code.
The issue in your code is that there are two `res` variable, `res.render` shoud use the first `res`.